# Correct edit rejection

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question, suggested-edits

As code edits are reviewed by peers, anyone who has rights to review the edits can approve or reject edits. I [suggested this edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/11063) and, AFAIK, my edits are correct. But this got rejected.

I know this sound harsh and arrogant, but I think non-specific-language programmers shouldn't approve or reject specific language programs.  For instance, a non-Java programmer shouldn't approve/reject any edit on Java program. I don't mean to attack personally; sorry if I did.

Comment: Since Lstor is familiar with Java, I'll take his word for it that the rejection was justified.  In general, though, anyone reviewing a specific code edit _should_ be familiar with that language, otherwise that review should be skipped.  Not doing so would cause something like this (if it happened that Lstor knew nothing of Java).

Comment: @WilliamMorris points out the reason for rejection: *Would it not be better to explain the problem in a comment rather than just changing the code?* For more details, see [this question on Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/762/should-you-edit-the-code-in-a-question).

Comment: To clarify: The (pre-defined) reason I chose was: *This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.* The *incorrect* here means "not a reason to edit the code", not that the code in the edit was invalid. The last part is the key part: **an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.** In other words, your edit would be better suited as a comment to the question. I'll make sure to state that more clearly the next time, like William Morris did.

Comment: @Lstor that meta topic isn't relevant here. That discussion is about editing questions, but this edit was to an answer.

Comment: @WinstonEwert Oh. You are right, of course. Then I must apologize, tintinmj. I made a mistake. I still think it's generally more useful to comment and clarify than to simply edit, but if I had realized it was an answer, I would have voted approve.